# Why is WebStorm highlighting all the file from the project pane?

Tags: webstorm

I suddenly came across an annoying problem using WebStorm. I don't know how I triggered this.

[image]

It's highlighting everything no matter what that is. I also notice that syntax colors are also broken, and Prettier doesn't work. Probably other things too. It seems just out of order.

I tried to restart, reinstall WebStorm, all without any effect. It doesn't behave like this on other projects. I have spent hours reading WebStorm documentation, but I don't find anything related to that issue.

Does anyone has a clue?

Comment: Are you using git?

Comment: Yes with every project

Comment: So can you talk a little more about what the problem is? I guess I didn't quite understand.

Comment: Well, the IDE is out of order on several features, and makes it very annoying to use.

No proper syntaxic coloration, the filetree pane is not properly highlighted, Prettier not working, unable to set it back. And I am clueless about how I can resolve the issue.

Comment: File > Settings > Version Control Remove the git. Then if you want to use again, use command `git init` this problem seems about git

Comment: Close WebStorm, backup and delete .idea folder in the project root.

Comment: Thank you very much, you found the issue @s0xzwasd !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your `.idea` files are broken, the `.iml` file and/or `modules.xml` are either missing or corrupted, so all the project files are treated as non-project.
Deleting and re-creating `.idea` folder should help:

- close the project
- remove it from **Recent projects** list
- shut down the IDE
- delete the `.idea` folder
- restart, open the project root folder with **File > Open**