# WebStorm yellowish project folders

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I cannot get rid of this problem.

[image]

The solutions mentioned on the internet are missing the places to be clicked. I cannot find the `mark as option` on the right-click context menu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is WebStorm highlighting all the file from the project pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69333499/why-is-webstorm-highlighting-all-the-file-from-the-project-pane)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably your `.idea` files are broken, the `.iml` file and/or `modules.xml` are either missing or corrupted, so all the project files are treated as non-project. Deleting and re-creating `.idea` folder should help:

- close the project
- remove it from **Recent projects** list
- shut down the IDE
- delete the `.idea` folder
- restart, open the project root folder with **File > Open**

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was going to go nuts.

Comment: Please [don't post duplicate answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). If the questions are the same, pick the best one to answer and then vote to close the other(s) as duplicates. If they're not the same, then tailor your answer to the specifics of each question. As both answers have been accepted I'll leave it up to you do decide which one to mark as a duplicate.