# IntelliJ Spring Boot Initializer with Maven: Yellow Background Project Files

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I used Spring boot initializer and created a Project. I tried opening with IntelliJ, but my project files background is yellow. I have Java and Maven installed. How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

This resource did not provide solution: [WebStorm yellowish project folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69468250/webstorm-yellowish-project-folders)

Currently using Windows.
I cannot even get the project to run, no option provided. I don't see option "Mark Directory as Source Root" [image]

[image]

Update: Opened Maven files as an Intelli Project, it removes the red lines in pom.xml file, but still cannot run it and yellow background files.

Comment: well, if you are  new to  spring and maven , you should have a look about quickstart  both of them . to slove the scenario   you  encoutering is  that  right click the path ```src/main/java  ``` and ```Mark dictory as source Root``` ,the same way  on   ```src/main/resource``` , and mark it as resource root

Comment: hi @Peng I don't see that option, rightclicking on source folder  https://ibb.co/t8RLc9m

Comment: may be your  IDEA  version is not supprt this feature , mine  idea version is ```IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Community Edition)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Recently  Answer

right-click directory and then mark directory as source root or resource root. If there is no  `mark as`   in your  IDEA  , please update your IDEA version ,  my version is `IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Community Edition)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general [list of IDEA's color codes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html) and [scope coloring](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html).

It looks like IDEA considers all files and folders "Non-Project Files", which normally only applies to SDKs and 3rd party libraries.

This might be a side-effect of the failed Project build/import, as seen on the first screenshot.
Seems like Maven is failing to resolve the dependencies.

There might be more issues, not shown on the screenshot.