# Can't see the .idea and src folder when creating Java Project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project, src

I know how to create a new Java Project in IntelliJ IDEA and I did it many times before. But one day when I start my application and try to make a new Java Project, I don't have the ability to see the .idea and src folder, I have only the .iml file. And don't have the ability to make a Java Class. I try everything, I either reinstall the application but without a change. Please help me. I have an exam in three days and I am panicking so much. Help

Comment: Make sure you have the valid module with the content roots defined, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69348378/104891.

Answer (score 0):

Since reinstalling IntelliJ Idea may leave settings in your user folder, you can try File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings. Then File -> New -> Project  and select Java on the left pane.